# Google Chrome command line switches

Tags: google-chrome

Are the Google Chrome command-line switches are documented somewhere?  I would like to have the list of all Chrome command-line switches.

Comment: Did you try a web search for "google chrome command line switches"?

Comment: Yes I did. I did not found any complete list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, here they are:

Run Chromium with flags:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

List of Chromium Command Line Switches:

http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: Those list doesn't seems to be complete. I heard recently of the --pinned-tab-count swtich. This switch is not in the list.  Are there other switches?

Comment: Haaaa. forget that. Just read the --pinned-tab-count switch is no longer supported by chrome.  [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37596).

Comment: Google Chromium is not Chrome, so this doesn't answer the question. Yes, I know, that both shared source code at some point and still do [share some], yet the two do not have to have same command line switches, and since Google doesn't say anything, Chrome's switches are in effect *undocumented*.

Comment: How can I get the values of the list?

Comment: Second link is broken.